# Trimming amount of many-to-many row combinations in bridge table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I have a bridge table to handle the Many-to-Many relationship that a Person can have to the Areas that they belong. Initially the Person table is loaded with the reference to his/her belonging Area based on their specific address. However as many Addresses basically point to the same single area or same set of multiple areas, I want to Trim/Consolidate the possible combinations into fewer rows in the bridge table (10million+ rows into 10k).
So first I want to generate the new bridge_area table and then populate a new person table with the new Key_Bridge value as per below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before doing this, a few things to consider:

- Have you changed your processes so this doesn't happen again? When adding new records, you can detect that you already have a mapping to the relevant areas and not create a new duplicate one.
- Do you have a plan for how you are going to drop the existing tables and use the new ones? If there are existing foreign keys and indexes, you'll need to account for all of that.

I'm sure there are many different ways of doing this, but one method I think will work:

```
SELECT key_bridge, cast(key_area.value as int) key_area
INTO bridge_area2
FROM
(
 SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY areas) key_bridge, areas
 FROM
 (
  SELECT
   DISTINCT STRING_AGG(key_area, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY key_area) areas
  FROM bridge_area
  GROUP BY key_address
 ) a
) b CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(areas, ',') key_area
```

The innermost query uses `STRING_AGG` to group the `key_area`s for each `key_address` together. For example, `key_address`=13 has `areas`="100,105". Since they are sorted in order, any `key_bridge` that has the exact same set of `key_area`s will have an exact match of `areas` so the `distinct` will limit this to the minimum number we need in the new `bridge_area` table. (It's important to use a delimiter here that can't exist in your data, but since your `key_area`s are numeric, a simple comma will do.)

`row_number()` is used to generate a new `key_bridge` column for each set of `areas` we care about, and the `cross_apply` is used to separate the `areas` (e.g. "100,105") back into separate rows. Note the `cast` to convert back to a numeric format.

Then you can create your new `person` table from that:

```
SELECT key_person, (SELECT key_bridge FROM bridge_area2 b2 GROUP BY key_bridge HAVING STRING_AGG(b2.key_area, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b2.key_area) = STRING_AGG(b1.key_area, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b1.key_area)) key_bridge
INTO person2
FROM person INNER JOIN bridge_area b1
  ON person.key_address = b1.key_address
GROUP BY key_person
```

This is similar to the previous query. For each `key_person`, it figures out the ordered `STRING_AGG` of all the relevant `key_area`s in the current `bridge_area` table and then finds the same ordered grouping of `key_areas`s in the new `bridge_area2` table.

You can [see this working in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WydoX538).

You now have the new tables you want and can rename them after dropping the old ones (with the caveats listed above about indexes, foreign keys, etc.)